# global variables for different javascript file

Tags: javascript

I have a web app, which has 2 html pages(html1,html2 related to javascript file js1.js,js2.js)
When I click a button on html1, it will navigate to html2.
I know there is the way transfer the parameter using url from html1/js1/js to html2/js2.js.

Is there a mechanism that set up variables both j1.js j2.js can access?(likes global variable in c)

Welcome any comment?

Comment: Related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981673/persist-javascript-variables-across-pages, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932782/global-variables-in-javascript-across-multiple-files, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416076/javascript-global-variables-shared-between-js-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hackish solution is to store it into the window.name field. This is shared in the same window/tab of the browser.
I personally don't like it. That variable isn't meant to be used this way.

There are libraries to persist state: http://pablotron.org/?cid=1557

Or, you could write your own code to store the variable in session (requires server-side programming), in HTML5 storage, in cookies, etc.

Comment: ADC's anwser is also a solution but I can not select 2 answers :-(

Answer (score 4):

This is not directly possible as each page loads with its own window object namespace.

i.e. A global variable in js1.js (used in page1.html) is actually a member of the window object in page1. Similarly a global variable in page2.html is a member of that page's window object. The 2 window objects are totally different in the sense **there is no site wide *window* or *site* object that can store global variable for use throughout a site**

You can however use `window.localStorage` to share variables/values across pages in your site.

**Example**:

Setting value:

```
window.localStorage.setItem('myglobal', "hello");
```

Getting value:

```
var myglobal = window.localStorage.getItem('myglobal');
```

Comment: Quick compatibility note: this isn't supported in IE7 or some mobile browsers, so if you plan to support these browsers then ensure this function is non-essential (I tend to work under the assumption that *all* JS should be non-essential anyway...)

Comment: If IE7 and older are to be supported, I suggest you take a look at a cookie based solution.

Answer (score 1):

Variables and values can be passed through pages via querystring.
Have a look at this [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870512/obtaining-querystring-from-current-url-in-javascript).

If you strictly need to create a Javascript global variable, then you have to include a common snippet in both pages:

```
var myGlobalVar;
```

But this only represent a storage accessible by both scripts. You have to set its value anyway.

Comment: The value of this global variable will still not travel across pages. I mean you can't set a value from page1 and get that value in page2 via the above method.

Comment: I get you. The query string method should work. Why don't you pass the value server side?

Answer (score 0):

You can either parse `window.location.href` to extract the parameters, set cookies in one page and retrieve them in the other ([example here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)) which also requires parsing or use a server-side solution.

Most probably if you look for in interwebs you can find parsers for URLs and Cookies.