# Accessing javascript variables across html files

Tags: javascript, php, html, parse-platform, global-variables

I am trying to use my js file to hold all of my variables that I will use across my html files to either update or retrieve the values. I feel silly because I was able to access the helpers.js variables from my index.html file but not my mainMenu.html. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am trying to get the first name of the user to my mainMenu.html.

I tried following this link as a reference but I am stuck:
 [[Global variables in Javascript across multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932782/global-variables-in-javascript-across-multiple-files])

---

My js file with all of the variables I will be referencing:

'helpers.js'

```
var companyName = "";
var firstName = "";
var lastName ="";
var clientOrEmployee ="";
var online = "";
var offline = "";



function setFirstName(val){
firstName = val;
}

function getFirstName(){
 return firstName;

}
```

My html file that is WORKING PROPERLY and acts as a login page. It shows that the information was entered in correctly (1 score matched), then it shows the company, user status, user first name and last name, and then it shows the first name as it is referenced by the helpers.js file, followed by how many online and offline information they have.

'index.html'

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="helpers.js"></script>
  <title>X2nSat</title>

    <style>
      .error {color: #FFFFFF;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <meta name="description" content="title">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.19.min.js"></script>


<body bgcolor="FFFFFF">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css"  />
    <div id="wrapper">
     <br><br><br>
      <div id="main">

       <center>
        <form name="myform">
          <br>

      <center>
    <img src="logo.png" />
     </center>
          <br>
          <center><h1>Login</h1></center>
          <br>


              <strong>Email: </strong>
              <br>
              <input type="text" name="email">
                     <span class="error">
                       <br>
                       <?php echo $emailErr;?>
                     </span>
                     <br><br>
              <strong>Password: </strong>
              <br>
              <input type="password" name="password">
                     <span class="error">
                       <br>
                       <?php echo $nameErr;?>
                      </span>
                 <br><br>
         <input type="button" value="Log In" name="Submit" onClick="validate()">
        </form>

        <br><br><br>
   </center>
  </div> <!-- main -->

  <script type="text/javascript" >
    Parse.initialize("secretID", "secretID");


    function validate() {

    var em = document.myform.email.value;
    var pw = document.myform.password.value;
    var valid = false;
/* =========
Query for finding email, password, company name, first name, last name and client or employee status   ================  */

    var Clients = Parse.Object.extend("Clients");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Clients);
    query.equalTo("email", em);
    query.equalTo("password",pw);
    query.find({
    success: function(results) {
    if(results.length==0){
      alert("Error: The information you have entered is incorrect. Please try again.");
    }
   else{
    alert("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " scores.");
    }

    // Do something with the returned Parse.Object values

 for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var object = results[i];
                var company = object.get('ComapnyName');
                var firstname = object.get('firstName');
                var lastname = object.get('lastName')
                var clientoremployee = object.get('client_or_employee');

                companyName = company;
                firstName = firstname;
                lastName = lastname;
                clientOrEmployee = clientoremployee;



                alert(company+ " "+clientoremployee + ' : ' + firstname+ ' ' + lastname);


        }//for loop end
 //start

alert(getFirstName()); //this is working 100%!!!!!!

/*=====
Query to find the number of online of offline sites
=====*/

var statusInfo = Parse.Object.extend("ClientCompanyInfo");
var query2 = new Parse.Query(statusInfo);
query2.equalTo("CompanyName", companyName);
query2.find({
  success: function(object) {
    // Successfully retrieved the object.

   var onlineCount = 0;
   var offlineCount = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
 var site = object[i];
      var status = site.get('site_status');
      if(status == "Online"){
        onlineCount++;
      }
      if(status == "Offline"){
       offlineCount++;
      }
     // alert(site.get('playerName'));
    }//end for loop

   online = onlineCount;
   offline = offlineCount;

   alert("Success: object length ="+object.length);
   alert("Online Sites: "+ onlineCount +" Offline: "+offlineCount);
   window.location.href = "mainMenu.html";

  },
error: function(error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});
       //end

       },//end if success
       error: function(error) {
       alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
       }//end error
    }); //find
 }//validate

  </script>
</div><!-- wrapper -->


  <!-- ============ FOOTER SECTION ============== -->

    <br><br><br>

    <div id="footer">

      <div style="position:relative; bottom:10px; text-align:center; width: 90%; margin:0 auto; height:30px; border:1px so\   
lid black;" >
    <id= "footer">
          Copyright &#169 Inc.

      </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

[image: loginscreen]

PROBLEMS: Everything is great UP TO THIS POINT... then I try to reference the helpers.js file in my mainMenu.html file and is giving me the value of 'undefined' as the user's first name. How is this possible? What am I missing???

'mainMenu.html'

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="helpers.js"></script>
<!--<script src="index.html"></script>-->
  <title>X2nSat</title>

    <style>
      .error {color: #FFFFFF;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <meta name="description" content="title">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.19.min.js"></script>

<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: 'Trebuchet MS',verdana;">

<table width="100%" style="height: 100%;" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" ><tr>


<!-- ============ LEFT COLUMN (MENU) ============== -->
<td width="30px" valign="top" bgcolor="FFFFFF">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="mainMenu.css"  />
  <div id="wrapper">

    <td style="vertical-align:middle" align="left">
      <div id="cssmenu">
        <ul>
          <li class="active"><a href="#"><span><center>Home</center></span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span><center>Sites</center></span></a></li>

    <li><a href="#"><span><center>Usage</center></span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span><center>Contact</center></span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span><center>Log Out</center></span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

</td>


<!-- ============ RIGHT COLUMN (CONTENT) ============== -->

<td width="81%" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

    <center>
      <img src="x2nsatLogo.png" />
    </center>

<h2><center>Site Report</center></h2>


<p>Welcome
  <script type="text/javascript" >
    Parse.initialize("secretID", "secretID");
    getFirstName();


  </script>
</p>


</div><!-- wrapper -->


</table>

</body>

</html>
```

[image: mainmenuscrren]

Can anyone help me out to why this file is having a hard time accessing the helpers.js getFirstName() function?

Thank you in advance!!!!!

P.S. Please let me know if you need me to clarify anything!!!!

Comment: Q: You have PHP in `.html` files extension. Did you instruct Apache to treat `.html` **"as"** PHP?

Comment: A: I am not 100% sure, but I do believe so. The PHP isn't giving my html files any problems that I am aware of.

Comment: So `<?php echo $emailErr;?>` etc. echoes out, correct? Just checking.

Comment: Another consideration: is `mainMenu.html` in the same directory location as `helpers.js`? If not, then it's probably 404ing on getting the JS file. See what your dev tools (F12) console says.

Comment: @Fred-ii-I just added a few pictures so that you can see what the file look like when it is loaded, before I fill out the information all have all of the alerts show me the correct information in the index,html file. I also included the image of my mainMenu.html file so that you can see that nothing is loaded next to the welcome.

Comment: @ajp15243 the files are in the same directory.

Comment: @MadsterMaddness Does `helpers.js` show up in the dev tools Network pane? This would indicate if it's getting loaded onto the page or not. Make sure there aren't any console errors (if there are, let us know what they are).

Comment: @ajp15243 I would think that using  '<script type="text/javascript" src="helpers.js"></script>' on the mainMenu.html page would mean that the file is being loaded onto the page. I will look into the network pane dev tool. I have never used it before. I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: @MadsterMaddness Well, that *should* load it onto the page :). Let us know if you are having trouble with the dev tools, they are a bit different for each browser, but are very powerful web development tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your JavaScript variable states will not be saved across pages. Everything in `helpers.js` starts over from the top, without any knowledge of previous page loads or other pages in the browser, every time you load the page.

If you want to pass values across pages, use `sessionStorage` (for modern browsers) or use cookies.

If you are using a desktop application you can use a database framework like [NeDB](http://npmjs.org/package/nedb). The syntax is similar to Mongo and it saves to a `.db` file.