# Wait for the javascript scripts (Google Charts) to load webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I have more than one script (for Google Charts) in the website and each one contains a loop (forEach) with $.Deferred() because I need it. When I have various scripts the website only show the result that the first has finished the ejecution and not the others. How I can wait until all scripts are finished to show the website.

I don't know if you can understand that I want to way.

Comment: Use an array to keep track of the Deffereds, and then use apply and done to know when all of them have been resolved

Comment: If you're having various `$.Deferred()` objects you can actually use [`$.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) to check when all the objects have been resolved.

Comment: Bucle = Loop. Sorry. With a $.each

Comment: How is $.when()? The $.Deferred() are in differentes scripts and I need all of them before the website. Is for Google Charts and I need to add the data

Comment: You collect the Deferreds in an array, and then do `$.when.apply($, arr).done(function() { . ..` which is what I suggested in the first comment !

Comment: But de Deferreds are in different scripts. I want that all scripts are excuted fow show correctly Google Charts with the correct data.

Comment: If the `$.Deferred` objects are global, then of course you can use them between different files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932782/global-variables-in-javascript-across-multiple-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write your scripts in footer or like:

```
 $(window).load(function() {
    //write your code.
 });
```

Comment: What? I have to put all the script inside your code? I have them now inside <head>

Comment: Writing scripts inside this will execute only after all DOM has loaded in the website.

Comment: But I want the scrips execute BEFORE the website to show Google Charts correctly

Comment: @BGG _"But I want the scrips execute BEFORE the website to show Google Charts correctly "_ Is requirement to execute several deferred processes _before_ calling google charts scripts ?

Comment: I use deferred to fill the data tables with a foreach from a JSON object. So, If I have a lot of charts I have a lot of deferred