# updating var in index.HTML from my javascript scripts

Tags: javascript, html

So as i'm new to coding, i decided to make a "snake" game. for those who dont know you are a snake and you go on a grid and random food pops up. when you eat the food your tail becomes longer and and longer and you cant hit the walls or yourself. it worked fine and i was so proud but upon trying to add a scoreboard to the game i've become lost. in my index.HTML i added a DIV and a variable using  and it displayed on the screen fine. what i cant figure out how to do is how to change the variable of the score from the javascript. my instinct was to go to where i had the code for "when you eat the food, you become longer" and add "also change score" but id need to update the index.HTML to do that. I named the variable "scoreVar" in my index.HTML and in the javascript i tried document.getElementById(scoreVar).innerHTML and tried updating the score by one but it wouldnt work. i asked people and searched online but nothing came up. PLEASE HELPPPPP!! thanks! :D

Comment: Don't tell stories. Show us the code and explain what is not working with the code. See also [How to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Global variables in Javascript across multiple files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932782/global-variables-in-javascript-across-multiple-files)

Comment: please make a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and put your working code in there so we can see what you have done till now and what is the problem. bu the way, you have `document.getElementById(scoreVar).innerHTML`, so what is exactly in the `scoreVar` variable? the score number? if so, you can not access the score element in your `html` by this code. you have to use the `ID` of the `div` which you created for the score...

Answer (score 0):

If you declare variables outside of functions, these are global variables that you can access from anywhere just by their name.  Consider this simple example.

A html file

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      var myCounter = 0;
    </script>
    <script src="file.js"/></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Hello World!</div>
    <button onclick="alert(myCounter);">Show counter value</button>
    <button onclick="IncreaseCounter();">Increase counter value</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

The referenced `file.js`

```
function IncreaseCounter()
{
    myCounter++;
}
```

Comment: hmmmm, are you sure this answer is for this question?! because his question is not related to the scopes but it's related to how to modify DOM...

Comment: @EhsanT Well, yeah, hard to tell, because the question is so verbose and confusing and has no code...