# How to get a variable from a function in HTML file to my javascript file in node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a function in my html file that has a javascript script runnning a function. I would like to take some of the variables from that function, and get them into the javascript file.

I already looked at the global variable as well as window, but both of them return an undefined variable, even though it has been set in my function in HTML. 
Below is part of the code showing the function in HTML and project_id is one of the variables id like in my javascript file. both my html and javascript file have the same name.

```
      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {

          //var test;
         // global.test = "hi";

           var results = e.target.result;

           var obj = JSON.parse(results);

          project_id = obj.project_id;
           client_email = obj.client_email;
          // private_key  = obj.private_key;

           //make it a hidden element 


          // Print the contents of the file
         var span = document.createElement('span');                    
         span.innerHTML = ['<p id= "data">',e.target.result,'</p>'].join('');
         document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
        };
      })(f);
```

Comment: You'll need something global to exchange values between scripts.

Comment: Do this `var global = (function () {return this;})();` near the beginning of your script then this `global.project_id = obj.project_id;` should work.

Comment: and then in the javascript file I reference it with global.project_id again?

Comment: check this- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932782/global-variables-in-javascript-across-multiple-files

Comment: I am using node.js and node red so:
<script type="text/javascript">
     // var project_id = handleFileSelect(evt); 

      var project_id;
      var client_email; 
      var private_key;
    (function () {

        RED.nodes.registerType('firebase config', {..

        ...
} 


and then later.. 

<script type="text/x-red" data-help-name="firebase config">

Comment: @SharonSoleman Yes, you reuse `global.project_id` when you need that value elsewhere in the file assuming they're in the same scope.

Comment: @SharonSoleman Is Node used as an http server?

Comment: @DominiqueFortin I am trying to use it in the javascript file after having declared it in the html file, but it is shown as being undefined. :( so same problem as before.

node-red is built on nodejs

Comment: @SharonSoleman An html file is executed by a browser application, but your script is run by a Node application, so they won't be able to share data without a communication channel.  Does this sounds right?

Comment: @DominiqueFortin  Both the html and the script are run by node and I can share data inputed into fields with the javascript file

Comment: @SharonSoleman What object/library name are you using to display/execute the html file?

Comment: it is within a node-module that I am editing for node-red

Comment: @SharonSoleman .. sorry i just saw it node-red it is

Comment: @SharonSoleman I can't see the whole picture.  I hope someone else will be able to help you.