# how can we declare a variable globally to use it in different script

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can we declare a variable globally so that we can use it in different different scripts written within same page.In below code how can i declare variable globally in script 1 so that i can used it in script 2.

**.php page**

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   //this is first script//
   </script >
  <script type="text/javascript">
   //this is second script//
   </script >
  </head>
 </html>
```

Comment: Have you declare and check once ?

Comment: yes i did but nothing happened, that variable is working within that script only.

Comment: Why you don't close your script tags?

Comment: Duplicate. See your answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932782/global-variables-in-javascript-across-multiple-files

Comment: no i dont want it from different file .i want to do within same file but 2 different script .can it be possible?@HassanImam

Comment: Maybe because you haven't declared any variable. The global scope is shared with all the scripts in the document, and all global variables are available in all scripts as well.

Comment: can you explain it in detail.@Teemu

Answer (score 1):

You need to properly closing the `script` tag .and declare the var in first one then access with below script .

**Order** of the script is more important.

if you add some other js link to handle `var a`.add this new link below the first one

**Updated**

1.defined variable validation
and replace the global varibale

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   //this is first script//
   var a ="hi"
   </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   //this is second script//
   if(typeof a !== "undefined") { // for defined varibale validation
   console.log(a)
   a='hello' // replaced
   console.log(a)
   }
   </script>
  </head>
 </html>
```

Comment: If you want to be sure that the variable is already init, you can check it with null test and init it else.

Comment: like if create var a="" in one script and then in second script can i assign a value to that 'a' variable?

Comment: @ArchanaGupta Note that last assign value are in your variable.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to create one file for global variable like
1st glob.js

and Code like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   //this is GLOBAL script//
   var a ="MY_FRIST_VAR"
   </script>
```

and used it as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="glob.js"></script>
 <script>
console.log(a)
<script>
```