# How to link a value from another file javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Right now i have a verifying code here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var i = prompt("Enter The Password: ");
     if (i === x) {
         window.location.href = '';
     }
     else {
         document.write("PASSWORD INVALID!!!")
     }
</script>
```

and another piece of code is here:

```
<script> <!-- not the same as above -->
    var x = prompt("Choose a password: ");
</script>
```

I would like to take the value from the 'choose a password' prompt in the second script, in order to create a password on the 'enter the password' prompt. Bascially the `x` variable in the second script must be the same as `x` variable in the first script. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not really clear what you are asking

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Global variables in Javascript across multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932782/global-variables-in-javascript-across-multiple-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly. You can export the 'x' variable from file and import it in the file where you need it.

You can read about imports and exports on MDN ([imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)) or somewhere else, there is a lot of examples on this topic.