# Retain the form values in HTML even after re-directed from another HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a Sample Registration form using HTML and JS. 
After filling out all the fields in the form, I have a href link, on clicking it, takes to new HTMl page for uploading documents and on clicking a button in the upload page...it then re-directs to the form page.
But the form page gets reloaded and so I am losing all the values given as input.

Comment: Maybe opening new page for uploading documents in new tab would help?

Comment: provide us code if possible

Comment: Use localStorage instead or put the information in the link and then parse the link when you load the new page.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way you can do this :

In the JavaScript of the first HTML file (where you get the data):

```
localStorage.setItem('variable',value)
```

and then retrieve it from another JavaScript file:

```
localStorage.getItem('variable')
```

Another approach:

[Global variables in Javascript across multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932782/global-variables-in-javascript-across-multiple-files)

Comment: Link can be temporary. Can you post your answer in this section