# Connecting js files

Tags: javascript

I have two halves of a JavaScript file which I would like to connect and I was wondering if someone might be able to help? I am looking to obtain the HTML form objects 'Title', 'Subtitle' and 'Body' from a HTML form. I then want to be able to pass these variables I have collected into the second half of the JavaScript file and post them into a SQL database.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var Title = $('#Title').val();
        var Subtitle = $('#Subtitle').val();
        var Body = $('#Body').val();
}
        
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('submit', 'form', function() {
    // Here you get the values:
    var Title = $('#Title').val();
    var Subtitle = $('#Subtitle').val();
    var Body = $('#Body').val();

    // OR
    // you have a simpler option:
    // var data = this.serialize();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        Title: Title,
        Subtitle: Subtitle,
        Body: Body
      },
      // OR
      // data: data, // if you use the form serialization above
      url: "/adddata",
      success: added,
      error: showError
    });
  });


  $("#submit").click(function() {
    console.log(id);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: "json",
      url: "/alldata",
      success: showScores,
      error: showError
    });
  });

});

var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;  
    var config = {  
        server: 'localhost',  //update me
        authentication: {
            type: 'default',
            options: {
                userName: '', //update me
                password: ''  //update me
            }
        },
        options: {
            // If you are on Microsoft Azure, you need encryption:
            encrypt: true,
            trustServerCertificate: true,
            database: 'Healthcare'  //update me
        }
    };  
    var connection = new Connection(config);  
    connection.on('connect', function(err) {
            if(err) {
                console.log('Error: ', err)
            } else {
        // If no error, then good to proceed.
        console.log("Connected");
        executeStatement();
        executeStatement1();
            }
    });
    
    connection.connect();
    
    var Request = require('tedious').Request;  
    var TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES;  
  
    function executeStatement() {  
        var request = new Request("SELECT * FROM dbo.Core;", function(err) {  
        if (err) {  
            console.log(err);}  
        });  
        var result = "";  
        request.on('row', function(columns) {  
            columns.forEach(function(column) {  
              if (column.value === null) {  
                console.log('NULL');  
              } else {  
                result+= column.value + " ";  
              }  
            });  
            console.log(result);  
            result ="";  
        });  
  
        request.on('done', function(rowCount, more) {  
        console.log(rowCount + ' rows returned');  
        });  
        
        // Close the connection after the final event emitted by the request, after the callback passes
        request.on("requestCompleted", function (rowCount, more) {
            connection.close();
        });
        connection.execSql(request);  
    }

    var Request = require('tedious').Request  
    var TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES;   
    
    function executeStatement1() {  
        var request = new Request("INSERT dbo.Core (Title, Subtitle, Body) VALUES (@Title, @Subtitle, @Body);", function(err) {  
         if (err) {  
            console.log("Couldn't insert data" + err);}  
        });  
        request.addParameter('Title', TYPES.NVarChar,'This is a test title from Javascript');  
        request.addParameter('Subtitle', TYPES.NVarChar , 'This is a test subtitle from Javascript');  
        request.addParameter('Body', TYPES.NVarChar, 'This is a test body from Javascript');    
        request.on('row', function(columns) {  
            columns.forEach(function(column) {  
              if (column.value === null) {  
                console.log('NULL');  
              } else {  
                console.log("Product id of inserted item is " + column.value);  
              }  
            });  
        });

        // Close the connection after the final event emitted by the request, after the callback passes
        request.on("requestCompleted", function (rowCount, more) {
            connection.close();
        });
        connection.execSql(request);  
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Global variables in Javascript across multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932782/global-variables-in-javascript-across-multiple-files)

Comment: Partially, yes. I've been able to link the HTML file with the Javascript Variables. I wondered if you knew how to subsequently insert those variables into SQL? I think i'm 90% of the way there, just need to tie up the loose ends.