How to access global variable defined in another JavaScript file from the current JavaScript file
I have a server JavaScript file that adds the IDs of all client sockets that connect to it to a list, I also have a second JavaScript file that has a method that should trigger a modal when the multiplayer button is clicked. I would like to access the list in the server file from the second JavaScript file and show the list of online users in a small modal.
Here is how am listening when a new user connects to the server, for now am adding the socket id and not the socket IP address to the list, which will be a more reliable way of identifying the client
Server.js
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('user with ' + socket.id + ' connected');
    //add that socket id to the list of online users connected to this server
    online_users.push(socket.id);
    
    socket.on('joinRoom', (room) => {
        socket.join(room);
        console.log(`User joined room: ${room}`);
    });

    socket.on('move', (data) => {
        const { room, message } = data;
        io.to(room).emit('move', message);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('user disconnected');
        //remove the client from the list of online_users
        online_users.wh
    });
});

The connection method for the socket is called and am able to see the id of the client that has connected and add it to a list.
I would like to show the list of online users inside a table that I will create programmatically and nest it inside the modal, but I have a problem with accessing the online_users variable and exposing it inside the JavaScript file below
//function to show who is online
//should call this method every second to get real time updates
function showOnline() {
    //get the list of online from the global exposed in the server.js
    
   //programmatically create a new table and show an avatar to the left alongside
   //the socket id of the user in the right
    $('#onlineModal').modal('show');
}


Have you tried exporting that variable from server file and import it into the another file?

@YashMaheshwari, How do I do that?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932782/global-variables-in-javascript-across-multiple-files

@YashMaheshwari No. OP has a server js file (presumably node.js, they didn't mention) and a client js file (in the browser, showing modals with jQuery). Those are two separate applications on different computers (talking to each other), you cannot just import one into the other!

@AnthonyKinyua You need to expose the list in an API, either via a HTTP request or via a message on your existing websocket connection. Your title is very much misleading btw, it's not just two files in the same application

@Bergi Agreed if its on different applications then this will not work, I was assuming that its in the same app.
